# Python - causes of ther error "OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor"

Tags: python, list, file

I get the error:

```
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

when my program calls up the line

```
with open(cs, 'r') as f :
    list = [line.strip() for line in f]
```

This refers to it opening the file 'cs' and reading it. The list is then created out of every line in the text file
I cant seem to work out what is going wrong, some guidance will be helpful

Thanks

EDIT:
The traceback doesnt seem to provide much:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sammy\Desktop\project 1\project1.py", line 85, in <module>
    main()  #run mainline
  File "C:\Users\Sammy\Desktop\project 1\project1.py", line 83, in main
    printCount(countVotes(candidateNumbers,getPapers(voteTXT,candidateNumbers)))
  File "C:\Users\Wen\Desktop\project 1\project1.py", line 53, in countVotes
    with open(cs, 'r') as `f :
```

Comment: Please post the full error traceback.

Comment: What is the value of `cs`?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters cs is a text file that holds names like this:
John
Billy
Nancy
with the names in a separate line

Comment: @SammyHD: that is not what I asked. `cs` is a *variable* containing a string (I presume).

Comment: if you are on windows, the file may be „locked” if opened in other app and the os return null or -1 as file descriptor. Before reading something from f, try print(type(f)), maybe you get more infos